# Сreating the first application for JavaSE

Tags: java

My name's Vladimir and I want to apologize for my bad English.

Ok. I started to learning Java SE and I need more practise for revise my knowledge.   I'd like to know this language much better than now.

How do you think, what program to create for beginner? Maybe server application with database? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Vladimir! Unfortunately, your question is offtopic for StackOverflow. We ask specific programming questions here. Good luck in your learning process and when you come across some technical problems, make sure to tune in! However, as of right now, your *question* is not well-suited to the site.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Vladimir Start with JAVA SE(core java) do hands on basics of core java, if your good with core java then you can start java EE(Advance java) where you can develop a web application using DB.
I suggest you to try some tutorial available for starting with java.
Happy Learning .. Do practice with code implementation in your Machine(Laptop/Desktop).

Comment: Victor Thanks for your answer. With respect, Vladimir.